# Select tag and Many to Many Relation in Rails 4.0

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

In my project i have 2 models 
Employee.rb

```
class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :shop
  ..
  ..
  ..
end
```

and Shop.rb

```
class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :employees
  ..
  ..
  ..
end
```

I'm not sure whether this relation is right or not. The working should be like this.
Employee got a foriegn key `employeeID` which is used in many tables..
If an employee has got more than 4 shops then 4 entries of the same employee will be in the employee table(employeeID will be same for all) and so on.
Now my issue is I have a form which updates the employee details. Form is used to create as well as edit employee details.
I want to put a select tag in this form which shows all the shops. On edit page the shops that belongs to the user should be preselected..

How to do this? Help

Comment: This is called a has-and-belongs-to-many (HABTM) relation and is covered in an [own chapter in Rails’ guides](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association).

Answer (score 1):

You should use the [`has_and_belongs_to_many`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-and-belongs-to-many-association) association:

[image]

--

**Has And Belongs To Many**

This will mean creating a new table:

```
#employees_shops
employee_id | shop_id
```

You can then associate the two models using the `has_and_belongs_to_many` declaration:

```
#app/models/employee.rb
Class Employee < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :shops
end

#app/models/shop.rb
Class Shop < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_and_belongs_to_many :employees
end
```

This will allow you to call:

```
@shop.employees.each do |employee|
    employee.name
end
```